# SonarQube log4j Vulnerability

Tags: security, sonarqube, log4j

How to detect the log4j vulnerability in SonarQube LTS 8.2 version any script for that.

I tried this community reference but not able to find for 8.2 version.

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-sonarcloud-and-the-log4j-vulnerability/54721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it refers to the sonar instance itself to prevent the vulnerability , maybe what you re looking for is kind a rule based on a regex pattern to check the package version. Try creating a new rule on sonar and add it to your quality profile